# Optional route params lost when access child route components Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I got a problem with optional route params, that route param (id) is lost when I access the child component

this is my route config on the router

```
{
  path: "route/:id?",
  component: () => import("*****"),
  props: true,
  children: [
    {
      path: "/",
      redirect: { name: "*****" }
    },
    {
      path: "information",
      component: () => import("****")
    },
  ]
},
```

this is my route expected `companies/1/description` etc

is there something wrong with my code?

this is how I push the router

it shows success like that `companies/1/information` but if i go through to another child route.. this param is lost like `companies/direction`

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction? What is the ID expected to be if it's omitted from the URL? What URL are you trying when  you "access the child component"?

Comment: Hi @tony19 Updated Questions

Comment: You seem to have accidentally deleted most of the info in your question. I undid that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you expect the `<router-link>` placed inside your `Company` component to somehow "inherit" route params from the current route automatically.

Unfortunately this is not how it works **with optional params** - it would work with non-optional params but optional params must be passed explicitly...

```html
:to="{ name: link.routeName, params: { id: $route.params.id } }"
```

```js
const companies = Vue.component('companies', {
  template: `
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/companies/1">Company 1</router-link>
    <router-link to="/companies/2">Company 2</router-link>

    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
  `
})

const company = Vue.component('company', {
  props: ['id'],
  template: `
  <div id="app">
    <h4> {{ id }} </h4>
    <h4> {{ $route.fullPath }} </h4>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'adminBusinessProfileInformation', params: { id: $route.params.id } }">Information</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'adminBusinessProfileDescription', params: { id: $route.params.id } }">Description</router-link>

    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
  `
})

const child = Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div>
    Child component
  </div>
  `
})

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
      path: '/',
      redirect: 'companies'
    },
    {
      name: 'companies',
      path: '/companies',
      component: companies
    },
    {
      path: '/companies/:id',
      component: company,
      props: true,
      children: [{
          path: "/",
          redirect: {
            name: "adminBusinessProfileInformation"
          }
        },
        {
          path: "information",
          component: child,
          name: "adminBusinessProfileInformation"
        },
        {
          path: "description",
          component: child,
          name: "adminBusinessProfileDescription"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/companies/1">Company 1</router-link>
  <router-link to="/companies/2">Company 2</router-link>

  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```